# How to import third party classes in .aidl file

Tags: android, rx-java, aidl

I want to create a service in its own process in order to communicate to different applications.

I'm following this guide http://www.donnfelker.com/rxjava-with-aidl-services/ but I'm having issue with the .aidl file.

This is my aidl interface:

```
// MyAidlInteface.aidl
package my.package;

import rx.Observable;

interface MyAidlInterface {
    Observable<Integer> getPid();
}
```

Android Studio gives me the following error and I don't know what to do:

`couldn't find import for class rx.Observable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. In order for this declaration to work, there would have to be an
   AIDL declaration for `rx.Observable`.  This is the source of the
   AndroidStudio error.  AIDL is not Java.  Just because
   `rx.Observable` is visible to the Java compiler does not mean it is
   visible to the AIDL compiler.  For your own sanity, it makes a *lot*
   of sense to put all of your AIDL into a separate top level source
   folder.  If it is not mixed up with your Java, then errors like this
   are much easier to spot.
2. The second problem is much more difficult to correct: That
   AIDL-visible declaration for `rx.Observable` would have to say
   something like:

> ```
> package rx;
>
> parcelable Observer;
> ```

Obviously, that won't work. `rx.Observer` is not Parcelable.  In order to do what you are trying to do you will have to create a Parcelable object with an AIDL definition, that is a proxy to the `Observer`.

Comment: can you please explain about creating a parcelable object of Observer (Proxy)? I am not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146041/how-do-i-make-my-realm-object-a-java-object/44210668#44210668