# How do I make my realm object a java object?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a database in realm and need to pass a realm object as a java object I have created in order for my adapter to recognise it.

```
public final static Parcelable.Creator<MoviePOJO> CREATOR = new Creator<MoviePOJO>() {

    @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
    })
    public MoviePOJO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        MoviePOJO instance = new MoviePOJO();
        instance.posterPath = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.overview = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.releaseDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.id = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.originalTitle = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.backdropPath = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        instance.voteAverage = ((Double) in.readValue((Double.class.getClassLoader())));
        return instance;
    }

    public MoviePOJO[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new MoviePOJO[size]);
    }
};
```

is the movie creator and my RealmObject is:

```
public class FavoritesItem extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey  private Integer movieId;
    private String moviePoster;
    private String movieBackdrop;
    private String movieTitle;
    private String movieOverview;
    private Double movieRating;
    private String movieReleaseDate;
}
```

How do I get one to the other?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/294714), please explain your actual use-case. For example, normally there would be no need for your adapter to receive a Parcelable.... especially when you're using Realm.

Comment: so I'm trying to retrieve the object as a MoviePOJO to pass it in an intent I already have

Comment: Why are you passing the whole object instead of requerying it by ID?

Comment: Unrelated and off-topic, but you realize there is a `readString` and `readDouble` method of the Parcel object?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce There are two objects here. What are you suggesting about querying?

Comment: @cricket_007 he wants to send the `FavoritesItem` through the intent, so I figured he actually wants to send `movieId` over instead. Also considering you'd generally want a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` with a `RealmResults<FavoritesItem>`, I'm actually not even sure what `MoviePOJO` is for.

Comment: Why do you have two classes in the first place, if they're modeling the same thing?  And if they're not modeling the same thing, what does it mean to "get one to the other"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that, as @cricket_007 suggests, you want to get an object from a Realm DB and then send it somewhere on an `Intent` (or vice-versa), you have a couple options.

By far the best would be to avoid sending the whole object.  If you are just sending it, say, to an `Activity` or an `IntentService`, within your own app, just send the primary key (probably `movieId`).  The recipient can open a Realm instance and select the same object.  This will be *far* faster than even parcelling.

If you absolutely must parcel, you are going to want an adapter, like this:

```
public class MovieParcelable implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<MovieParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieParcelable>() {
        @Override
        public MovieParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            int id = in.readInt();
            String poster = in.readString();
            // ...
            double rating = in.readDouble();
            String releaseDate = in.readString();
            return new MovieParcelable(id, poster, ..., rating, releaseDate);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieParcelable[size];
        }
    };

    private final Movie movie;

    public MovieParcelable(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    MovieParcelable(int id, String poster, ..., double rating, String releaseDate) {
        this(new Movie(id, poster, ..., rating, releaseDate));
    }

    public Movie getMovie() { return movie; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() { return 0; }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(movie.getId());
        dest.writeString(movie.getPoster());
        // ...
        dest.writeDouble(movie.getRating());
        dest.writeString(movie.getReleaseDate());
    }
}
```